# How to get latest data from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have `an array of objects and each object has updatedDate`.
I am trying get the latest UpdatedDateusing following lines of javascript but it `returns NaN` to me.

```
var maxDate = Math.max.apply(Math, obj.reportsArray.map(function (o)
{
    return o.UpdatedDate;
}))
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: can you extend your question with the information on the contents of your obj? something alike `console.log(obj.reportsArray)` would be fine. I think the issue is with the data array itself, there are not numbers only.

Comment: I saw in console, the date is in this format '2016/03/17 22:15:57' in each object of the array.

Comment: see my answer below, because it's bigger than just a comment. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) function requires type `Numbers`, and you are getting `NaN` when try to use it for different type of data.

You need to convert the [`Date` object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to number, alike `getTime()` or similar function [`valueOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp), and if you need to get result at `Date` as well - then to convert `Number` back to `Date`.

```
var maxDate = Math.max.apply(Math, obj.reportsArray.map(function (o)
{
    return o.UpdatedDate.valueOf(); // <-- here you need the convertion of Date object
}))
```